# How do I cache an image generated by PHP with a GET parameter

Tags: php, caching, query-string

I've seen a lot of people ask about how to cache images generated with a PHP script. This is quite simple to do, but I am not sure if it'll cache images generated using a querystring.

I plan on storing a MySQL database to store users' avatars in BLOBs, but fetching those images will require PHP. So I write a simple PHP script to fetch the image and print it in jpeg, but will the browser cache it when the URL contains a querystring?

Assuming my script is named `avatar.php` and it depends on a GET variable named `user`. A users avatar could be viewed by visiting avatar.php?user=1. Using these headers, would the browser cache the image?

```
header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800");
header("Pragma: private");
header("Expires: " . date(DATE_RFC822,strtotime(" 7 day")));
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])){ 
    // if the browser has a cached version of this image, send 304 
    header('Last-Modified: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'],true,304); 
    exit; 
}
```

Comment: I don't see what's stopping you from trying it out yourself and seeing the results first?

Comment: @php_nub_qq How would I know that? They're rather small images so I can hardly tell the difference in load time.

Comment: Well you could delete the image from the database and see if it's still loading?

Comment: Firebug and Google Page Speed will both tell you if a resource is fetched from the cache or the site.

Comment: Appearantly it IS cached but I messed something up in my browser...